# Hodge structure on intersection cohomology of toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, perverse-sheaves, intersection-cohomology, hodge-structure

Given a convex polytope with integer vertices, one can construct a complex projective variety $X$ called toric variety. In general $X$ is not smooth. As I have heard, by the work of M. Saito, the intersection cohomology of any projective complex variety, in particular of $X$, carries a natural pure Hodge structure.

**Is it true that it satisfies
$$H^{p,q}=0 \mbox{ if } p\ne q?$$**

This is known to be the case if $X$ is smooth.

Comment: I am tempted to argue as follows: $X$ has a toric resolution $Y\rightarrow X.$ By the decomposition theorem, the intersection cohomology of $X$ is a direct summand of the cohomology of $Y$, and as you note, the cohomology of $Y$ is Hodge-Tate.